# First plot with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have to a plot like this with Tikz and pgfplot:

[image]

I have never used pgfplot and I am just learning how to use it. So far I have done only the axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
compat=newest, %footnotesize
tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
label style={font=\small},
legend style={font=\small},
axis x line = center,
axis y line = center,
every axis/.style={pin distance=1ex},
trim axis left   
}   %%%% fin pgfplotsset


 \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
   axis x line=center,
   axis y line=none,
   xmin=-3,xmax=3,
   xticklabels={$s_{k-4}$, $s_{k-3}$, $s_{k-2}$, $s_{k-1}$, $s_k$, $s_{k+1}$}
   ]
  \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture} 
 \end{document}
```

At this point, how to draw the step u? I would be glad if someone can help understanding how to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't edit your question significantly) when there is an answer and then ask another question. Please ask a [Follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) for that. I will revert the question to its old state now ...

Comment: Sorry for that! But I haven't seen the answer when I edited my question, that's why I made some updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *many* ways to achieve what you want. Here I present one of these.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the "advanced" placing for the
        % axis labels
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % we want to reduce the `height' of the graph without rescaling the `widht'
        width=\axisdefaultwidth,
        height=3cm,
        % (I use `bottom' to draw the line from 0 to 1, so if needed by using
        %  the value `center' I can easily put it *on* the drawn line if needed)
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=none,
        % -----
%        % add (pure) "z" label (without the arrow)
%        xlabel=$z$,
        % -----
        % add the arrow with the "z" label
        % (I do it in this way, because it would also work when `clip=true'
        %  would be used. Using the `xticklabel cs' (coordinate system) has
        %  the advantage that it respects the size of the xticklabels and thus
        %  would also work, if you would change the font size to e.g. `\Huge'. The given "y" coordinate is used to add an additional yshift (in this case).)
        after end axis/.code={
            \draw [->] (xticklabel cs:0.25,1ex)
                -- node [below] {$z$}
                    (xticklabel cs:0.75,1ex)
            ;
        },
        % -----
        % (adjusted a bit)
        xmin=-2.5,
        xmax=2.5,
        % change this value to state the "offset" of the x axis to the plot
        ymin=-0.5,
        % to sync the ticks with the labels ...
        xtick={-2,...,2},
        xticklabels={$s_{k-2}$, $s_{k-1}$, $s_k$, $s_{k+1}$, $s_{k+2}$},
        % we don't want to draw markers
        no markers,
        % turn of clipping so the nodes above the plot aren't clipped away
        clip=false,
    ]
        % one of many possible ways to draw the line in question is to just
        % provide some coordinates
        \addplot coordinates { (-2.5,0) (0.5,0) (0.5,1) (2.5,1) }
                % provide options used for all following nodes
                [above]
            % add nodes to the plot at specified `pos'itions
            node [pos=0.25] {$U_{k-3}$}
            node [pos=0.80] {$U_{k-2}$}
        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot! very nice explaination! I think I can draw also the arrow tau below the axis in the same way of u, right?

Comment: You could, but there is a "better" (not necessarily easier) way to do that. See the edit of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see you are in the process of adapting to `pgfplot`. I'd be glad to help you. I'll post source code as well as the result of my compiling (I'm using TeXLive). I suggest you to use plain `tikz` before `pgfplot` instead, as it is more beginner-friendly and doesn't involve a plethora of long functions. Because of this, I'll be using plain `tikz`. Of course, If you *insist* on `pgfplots` solution, I'll post that as well, just let me know.

Anyway, here's the `tikz` code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
\node at (-0.3,0) {$\cdots$};
\node at (10.3,0) {$\cdots$};

\node at (2,0) {$|$};
\node at (4,0) {$|$};
\node at (6,0) {$|$};
\node at (8,0) {$|$};
\node at (10,0) {$|$};
\node at (2,-2) {$|$};

\node at (2,-0.5) {$s_{k-2}$};
\node at (4,-0.5) {$s_{k-1}$};
\node at (6,-0.5) {$s_{k}$};
\node at (8,-0.5) {$s_{k+1}$};

\node at (2,-2) {$\bullet$};
\draw[->] (2,-2) to node [below] {$z$}(7.2,-2);

\draw node at (-0.3,1) {$\cdots$};
\draw (0,1) to node [above] {$u_{k-3}$}(7.2,1);

\draw[dashed] (7.2,-2.5) to (7.2,1);
\draw (7.2,1) -- (7.2,2.5);
\draw(7.2,2.5) to node [above] {$u_{k-2}$}(10.5,2.5);
\node at (10.8,2.5) {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I know it's a little primitive, especially the `|` spam part (if I used the right commands I would get the same result with only one line of code), but I can't avoid such examples, as I want to show you simplicity sometimes *is* the right decision, especially for newcomers. Please don't feel offended by the fact that I posted `tikz` and not `pgfplot` solution. From experience I sensed my decision of presenting a less complex solution would be of benefit to you.

Have a good day.